# Extracting gradients of weight of ONNX model

Tags: onnx, onnxruntime

I am currently working on the testing of DL libraries. Specifically, I want to extract the gradients of weights of ONNX model to do differential testing.

However, I have read a lot of posts online but still could not find a clear way to extract the gradients of weights given an input of an ONNX model. Is there any API to access the gradients of ONNX model?

Thank you so much!

I have read many posts but cannot find any APIs to access the gradients of weights of ONNX   model.